# Updating data in an iPhone app daily?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to make a index card app, And I want to add a new word everyday. How would I go about that without updating the whole app through ITC and waiting a week?

Answer (score 1):

Have your app remotely connect to a server you've set up to refresh its data dynamically on whatever schedule you please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how the hell would i do that ? lol ....Kind of new to developing.

Comment: @TonyMallin well, that's a big complex topic... If you are new to iOS development and new to server development, I would highly recommend learning them in isolation before woking on a project that requires both.